# Error 500 on Wordpress (Magento Integration)

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9 and have installed wordpress in root/blog folder. Here is how my htaccess file looks like. I see an error 500 on blog. Magento site works well though.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way

But setting up permissions did the job.

```
 7       5    5
 user   group  world
 r+w+x  r+x    r+x
 4+2+1  4+0+1  4+0+1 = 755
```